# lightbox and slimbox2 doesn't work with composite c1

Tags: lightbox, composite, slimbox

I'm trying to use both lightbox and slimbox with Composite c1 v3.
Neither works.

I have installed the relevant packages and I have set correctly the parameters for both functions.
The result is that when I use lightbox both thumbnail and the picture appears on the page.
When I use slimbox2, the thumbnail is fine but the picture opens to a new page.

I have tried it both with IE 9 and firefox 9.0.1 with the same result.

As far as Composite C1 is concerned, I'm working on Omnicorp example site.

Anyone with the some kind of problem?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the [Slimbox2 package](http://docs.composite.net/Packages/CompositeMediaPackages/Slimbox2) and it worked for me in Chrome and IE. I had success installing the package, going to a page in Content, and inserting the function. Then I picked the Media Folder parameter, and set it to be a constant and selected a folder path. Once published, the slimbox behaved as expected. I am not working with the Omnicorp demo, however.

The behavior sounds to me like some part of the script isn't loading or is loading in the wrong order. Does the Omnicorp site, or another package have conflicting jQuery import(s) in the head section of a published page?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the packages have a bug,  when site is running in sub-folder the javascripts files are not loaded.
Do you run your site in subfolder?
Try to fix this.
Go to **Functions** perspective -> Xslt functions -> locate function **Composite.Media.ImageGallery.Slimbox2**  -> edit its template and fix links to the files, add **~** at the begin:

<script id="slimbox2-js" src="**~**/Frontend/Composite/Media/ImageGallery/Slimbox-2.04/js/slimbox2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link id="slimbox-2.04" media="screen" type="text/css" href="**~**/Frontend/Composite/Media/ImageGallery/Slimbox-2.04/css/slimbox2.css" rel="stylesheet" />

also locate function **Composite.Web.Html.Lightbox**, edit its template and fix links to the files (add **~**): 
<script id="html-lightbox-js" src="**~**/Frontend/Composite/Web/Html/Lightbox/js/jquery.html-lightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link id="html-lightbox-css" media="screen" type="text/css" href="**~**/Frontend/Composite/Web/Html/Lightbox/css/html-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: Packages were fixed, you can uninstall and install new versions

Comment: Thanks very much! The solution is exactly waht you say.